# preview image before upload - what does this line of code checks?

Tags: javascript

So I was looking for a way to preview an image before it is uploaded and I came across this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
</body>
```

It works great but there is something I don't understant.

What does **if(input.files && input.files[0])** really do?

I know that input.files returnes an FileList object that lets you access the list of files selected with the `<input type='file'>` element and that input.files[0] returns the first file in the node's file list but I can't seem to understand what that line of code is checking...

Thanks!

Comment: It checks that the input object has a `files` property, and that it has a file in `[0]`, the first index.

Comment: Ok now I understand what that line of code is doing and thanks for the response @adeneo but I'm still a little bit confused... Why does he need to check that the input object has a files property? I mean the method readURL gets called when the state of the input of type file gets changed so that input will always have a files property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(input.files && input.files[0])
```

Checks if the input object contains an element called files using AND its checking to see if the files object is an array with at least on element in it

Comment: thanks for the response @Husman, now I get what that line of code does but now I don't understand why does he do that? The method readURL gets called when the state of the input of type file gets changed so doesn't that mean that the input will always have an element called fils?

Comment: onChange reports all changes, even when a file has been selected or deselected. It is good practice to check if the element is null (as the browser or security setting may disallow certain files or file size. Also can you upvote the answer if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I think I get it now, thanks again. I'm afraid I can't upvote the answer, it says that I need at least 15 points of reputation in order to do this, I only have 9....